# Babel plugin react relay

Tags: reactjs, graphql, babeljs, relay, babel-relay

I am trying to setup a graphql project. I already have the GraphQL server running and trying to setup a relay environment. I have followed the instructions from here https://github.com/graphcool/babel-plugin-react-relay but when I try and run my project I get the following error:

> Project@1.0.0 start /Users/JKB/Sites/Project
>   nodemon --watch server --exec babel-node -- server/index.js

```
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: /Users/JKB/Sites/project/server/**/*
[nodemon] starting `babel-node server/index.js`

/Users/JKB/Sites/project/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-relay/lib/index.js:27
throw error;
^
Error
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/JKB/Sites/project/node_modules/node-fetch/index.js:133:11)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:285:9)
at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at _handle.close (net.js:501:12)
at TCP.done [as _onclose] (_tls_wrap.js:325:7)
at module.exports.loopWhile (/Users/JKB/Sites/project/node_modules/deasync/index.js:72:22)
at exports.default (/Users/JKB/Sites/project/node_modules/babel-plugin-react-relay/lib/index.js:21:26)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I have the following .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [ "es2015", "react" ],
    "plugins": [ "react-html-attrs", "react-relay" ]
}
```

and I have exported the environment variable:
    export GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:3000/graphql"

and the following package versions:

```
"babel-relay-plugin": "^0.10.0"
"babel-plugin-react-relay": "^0.10.0"
"react-relay": "^0.10.0"
```

When I try to reinstall I get the following warnings - not sure if they are related..

```
Project@1.0.0 /Users/JKB/Sites/project
├── babel-plugin-react-relay@0.10.0 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY babel-relay-plugin@0.11.0 invalid

npm WARN react-relay@0.10.0 requires a peer of babel-relay-plugin@0.10.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN Project@1.0.0 No repository field.
➜  project git:(master) ✗ npm install -D babel-relay-plugin      
Project@1.0.0 /Users/JKB/Sites/project
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY babel-relay-plugin@0.11.0

npm WARN react-relay@0.10.0 requires a peer of babel-relay-plugin@0.10.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN Picso@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `babel-plugin-react-relay` to setup the GraphQL server. This plugin are used by the client not the server.

You can run the GraphQL server without this plugin. However, for consuming that server with a Relay client, you need to configure the plugin - only in the client.

See a full example of GraphQL server for Relay client apps in this repository: https://github.com/danielfeelfine/graphql-relay-server. You need [this script](https://github.com/danielfeelfine/graphql-relay-server/blob/master/scripts/updateSchema.js) to generate a JSON with schema introspection for [Babel Relay Plugin](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-babel-plugin.html).

And finally, here an example of Relay client app (using React Native), consuming the GraphQL server, in this repository: https://github.com/danielfeelfine/react-native-relay. The [.babelrc](https://github.com/danielfeelfine/react-native-relay/blob/master/.babelrc) containing the configuration for `babel-relay-plugin` what you need to use.

Comment: Sorry, should have made is clear. I already have GraphQL server running on localhost port 3000. I am trying to set up the relay environment and thats the error I get.

Comment: Have you tried not to use `babel-relay-react-plugin` and only `babel-relay-plugin` according the example above?